# Remove Underline under FLTK Menu Options

Tags: fltk

I'm creating a MenuBar in FLTK, and can't figure out how to remove the little underlines under each menu category. What setting controls this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify the labels of menu's entries, you have to remove `&`: see the examples below.

With `&`:

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Double_Window.H>
#include <iostream>
#include <FL/Fl_Menu_Bar.H>
int main() {
    Fl_Double_Window* G_win = new Fl_Double_Window(200,200);
    Fl_Menu_Bar *menu = new Fl_Menu_Bar(0,0,400,25);
    
    menu->add("&File"); // F is underlined
    menu->add("Edi&t"); // t is underlined

    G_win->show();
    return(Fl::run());
}
```

Without `&`:

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Double_Window.H>
#include <iostream>
#include <FL/Fl_Menu_Bar.H>
int main() {
    Fl_Double_Window* G_win = new Fl_Double_Window(200,200);
    Fl_Menu_Bar *menu = new Fl_Menu_Bar(0,0,400,25);
    
    menu->add("File"); // No letter is underlined
    menu->add("Edit"); // No letter is underlined

    G_win->show();
    return(Fl::run());
}
```

In the last case, the label of each menu does not have any underlined letter. See [here](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__Menu__.html#ac380c9009765c4288577f01af9a3e4d5) for a more detailed explanation.